# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /login/ User has no profile

Tags: python, django

Profile creation for every new user was working properly. But when I resize the image quality of the user profile from my 'models.py' file, then whenever I create a new user it doesn't create profile for that new user. How do I solve this problem? My codes are given below:

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserSignupForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Signup for {username} is successful')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'title': 'signup', 'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'title' : 'Profile'
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)


@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_update = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_update = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_update.is_valid() and profile_update.is_valid():
            user_update.save()
            profile_update.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        user_update = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_update = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
        'title' : 'Update Information',
        'u_form' : user_update,
        'p_form' : profile_update
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile_update.html', context)
```

**signals.py:**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Full Name', max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Full Name', max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

and
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}\'s Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: Can you share the `Profile` model that you are using?

Comment: I post my 'models.py' as a answer below.

Comment: you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Sumithran nope

Comment: @BsJoy: you should [edit] the question, not post this as an answer.

Comment: @BsJoy check the updated answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I don't know it is the right way or not but it's working for me. So the solution is I just change the default image extension from '.jpg' to '.png' in the profile model class and the default picture image extension.[image]

[image]

Maybe the PIL library doesn't support the '.jpg. format.